# Schema validate causes Save to fail in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Why does the following code causes the Mongoose `save` to fail?  If I remove `validate: utils.uuid.isValid` (returns a boolean) the process will complete:

```
var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    _id : { type: String, default: utils.uuid.init, validate: utils.uuid.isValid },

    n   : { type: String }, // Display Name

    ac  : { type: Date },
    au  : { type: Date },
    ad  : { type: Date },
    am  : { type: String }
});
```

Also, if I remove the `validate` property of the field, and try setting values in the `pre('validate', cb)` or `pre('save', cb)` call, this will cause the same result:

```
accountSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
    var now      = new Date(),
        memberId = this.am;
    console.log('In Account validate (member : ' + memberId + ')');
    if (this.isNew) { this.ac = now; console.log('Item is new.'); }
    else if (this.isModified()) { this.au = now; console.log('Item is modified.'); }
    else { return next();
        console.log('Canceling Account validate.');
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this));
    console.log('Completed Account validate.');
    next();
});
```

Nothing crashes.  In Webstorm, processing just stops with a message "Process finished with exit code 139".

Comment: Can you share with us the stack trace?

Comment: Nothing crashes.  In Webstorm I get 'Process finished with exit code 139' and processing simply stops.

Comment: humm... Do you really need to overwrite the default _id algorithm? I'm asking this because I never needed to do this and I can't see a good reason to do so. The _id is automatically created by the Mongoose for you, so you don't need to declare the _id in your Schema.

Comment: @danilodeveloper For this client, yes, I do.